# Описать тип , возвращающий тип N-нного аргумента функции Fn

Tags: typescript

FN -  Generic-аргумент, принимающий только функции.
N -  Generic-аргумент, принимающий только числа. Показывает индекс аргумента, тип которого необходимо получить.

Тесты:

```
const numberParam: FunctionParameter<(arg: number) => void, 0> = 100  
const stringParam: FunctionParameter<(arg1: string, arg2: string) => void, 1> = 'Hello world!'  
const undefinedParam: FunctionParameter<(arg1: string, arg2: boolean) => void, 9312> = undefined
```

Решил так, решение работает, но ругается.

```
type FunctionParameter<Fn extends (...args:any) => any, N> =  
 Fn extends (...args:infer P) => any? P[N] : never
```

Есть ли способы получше?

Comment: что значит _решение работает, но ругается_?

Comment: Type 'N' cannot be used to index type 'P'. Но при этом работает все

Comment: добавь это в вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TS ругается потому что `N` может быть любым типом, в том числе таким, по которому аргументы не индексируются. Решение - ограничить `N` ключами массива аргументов. Так же в TS уже есть встроенный тип `Parameters<F>` для получения типов аргументов, буду использовать его для простоты понимания.

Поскольку мы знаем, что список аргументов всегда является массивом, мы можем просто ограничить `N` типом `number`:

```typescript
type NthParameter<F extends (...args: any[]) => any, N extends number> = Parameters<F>[N];
```

Либо можно напрямую ограничить его ключами используемого объекта:

```typescript
type NthParameter<F extends (...args: any[]) => any, N extends keyof Parameters<F>> = Parameters<F>[N];
```